# SQL Server: Display only the values that the condition is met

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to modify my query to show only the values that the condition is met.

My query:

```
SELECT
    name = r.RscMaster_Name_Ch
    ,Start_date = a.assign_from_da
    ,End_date = a.Assign_Thru_Da
FROM DW_WFTS.dbo.Assign_Tbl a
LEFT JOIN DW_WFTS.dbo.Resource_Master_Tbl r ON r.RscMaster_No_In = a.RscMaster_No_In
WHERE
    (
        a.Assign_Thru_Da >= GETDATE()
        OR a.Assign_Thru_Da IS NULL
        OR
        (
            a.Assign_From_Da >= GETDATE()
            AND a.Assign_Thru_Da >= GETDATE()
        )
        OR
        (
            a.Assign_From_Da <= GETDATE()
            AND a.Assign_Thru_Da <= GETDATE()
        )
    )
    AND
    (
        (
            a.Assign_From_Da LIKE '0%'
            OR a.Assign_From_Da LIKE '00%'
            OR a.Assign_From_Da LIKE '000%'
        )
        OR
        (
            a.Assign_Thru_Da LIKE '0%'
            OR a.Assign_Thru_Da LIKE '00%'
            OR a.Assign_Thru_Da LIKE '000%'
        )
    );
```

So if there are one or more users with the wrong date format - any year that is entered as '0YYY' or '00YY' or '000Y' - I want the query to display the name and only the wrong dates, like.

```
name       Start_date     end_date
John       0019-12-01
Jane                       0020-01-05
Mike       0019-01-05      0019-12-01
```

I'm not sure how I can omit the correct dates from the select. Please help.

Comment: Use CASE Statement https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp
If you can give more detail about the Table and Rows then i can specifically help you on this.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `Assign_From_Da` and `Assign_Thru_Da`?

Comment: Please expand on the definition of "wrong dates". Describe the criteria that makes a date wrong.

Comment: @digital.aaron - date.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You've already received an answer to the question as asked, and you can't change it after it's been answered to a different question. If you now have a different question, use the *Ask Question* button at the top of the page and ask it there. Changing the question after it's been answered can make the answer invalid, which will most likely cause it to be downvoted as being wrong; that is unfair and inappropriate for the person who took the time to answer you.

Comment: @KenWhite - Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is only a leading zero in the year

> "any year that is entered as '0YYY' or '00YY' or '000Y'"

and they are of type `DATE`, then this would get you there:

```
SELECT
    name = r.RscMaster_Name_Ch
    ,Start_date = a.assign_from_da
    ,End_date = a.Assign_Thru_Da
FROM DW_WFTS.dbo.Assign_Tbl a
LEFT JOIN DW_WFTS.dbo.Resource_Master_Tbl r ON r.RscMaster_No_In = a.RscMaster_No_In
where
    a.assign_from_da < '1000-01-01'
    or a.Assign_Thru_Da < '1000-01-01'
```

If you have more rules for dates, then the where clause could be expanded

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISDATE() function. It returns zero for character expression that is invalid date.

`SELECT
    name = r.RscMaster_Name_Ch
    ,Start_date = a.assign_from_da
    ,End_date = a.Assign_Thru_Da
FROM DW_WFTS.dbo.Assign_Tbl a
LEFT JOIN DW_WFTS.dbo.Resource_Master_Tbl r ON r.RscMaster_No_In = a.RscMaster_No_In
WHERE ISDATE( a.assign_from_da ) = 0
OR 
ISDATE( a.Assign_Thru_Da ) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The `DATE` type in SQL Server supports values from `0001-01-01` to `9999-12-31`. The `SMALLDATETIME` type allows values from `1900-01-01` through `2079-06-06`.
You can use `TRY_CAST()` to attempt to convert to `SMALLDATETIME` and then cast it back to a date. Any values that fall outside of `1900-01-01` through `2079-06-06` would then come back as NULL.

```
SELECT
    name = r.RscMaster_Name_Ch
    ,Start_date = CAST(TRY_CAST(a.assign_from_da AS SMALLDATETIME) AS DATE)
    ,End_date = CAST(TRY_CAST(a.Assign_Thru_Da AS SMALLDATETIME) AS DATE)
FROM DW_WFTS.dbo.Assign_Tbl a
LEFT JOIN DW_WFTS.dbo.Resource_Master_Tbl r ON r.RscMaster_No_In = a.RscMaster_No_In
WHERE
    (
        ISNULL(a.Assign_Thru_Da, DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())) >= GETDATE()
        OR
        (
            a.Assign_From_Da >= GETDATE()
            AND a.Assign_Thru_Da >= GETDATE()
        )
        OR
        (
            a.Assign_From_Da <= GETDATE()
            AND a.Assign_Thru_Da <= GETDATE()
        )
    )
```

You can then plug this query into your `sp_send_dbmail` call like this:

```
BEGIN

IF @count > 0

BEGIN

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    --@profile_name='emailFrsdata2',
    @recipients=N'won.chang@montgomerycountymd.gov',
    @subject = 'WFTS - Incorrect Assignment Dates found',
    @query = N'SELECT
                    name = r.RscMaster_Name_Ch
                    ,Start_date = CAST(TRY_CAST(a.assign_from_da AS SMALLDATETIME) AS DATE)
                    ,End_date = CAST(TRY_CAST(a.Assign_Thru_Da AS SMALLDATETIME) AS DATE)
                FROM DW_WFTS.dbo.Assign_Tbl a
                LEFT JOIN DW_WFTS.dbo.Resource_Master_Tbl r ON r.RscMaster_No_In = a.RscMaster_No_In
                WHERE
                    (
                        ISNULL(a.Assign_Thru_Da, DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())) >= GETDATE()
                        OR
                        (
                            a.Assign_From_Da >= GETDATE()
                            AND a.Assign_Thru_Da >= GETDATE()
                        )
                        OR
                        (
                            a.Assign_From_Da <= GETDATE()
                            AND a.Assign_Thru_Da <= GETDATE()
                        )
                    )
                ORDER BY r.RscMaster_Name_Ch',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0

END 

END
```